# Увеличить объем файлов загружаемых на сервер

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

не могу загрузить картинку на сервер больше 2мб не могу понять в чем проблем php.ini поменял поставил `post_max_size = 30M   upload_max_filesize = 30M` вроде все должно работать но чет нехочет

```
echo $_FILES['img1']['error'];
```

выдает ошибку 1 а это значит что объем картинки слишком большой может быть еще где нибудь поменять нужно на сервере установлена операционная система ubuntu и на нем стоит nginx

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart nginx рестартил
```

Comment: Что значит ошибка 1? Код ответа http проверяли? Может у вас сам nginx не хочет принимать большой файл. Это указывается параметром client_max_body_size 100M в разделе http {...} в конфиге nginx

Comment: systemctl restart php7.0-fpm делали? Что в логах nginx и php?

Comment: @Localhost спасибо большое  
systemctl restart php7.0-fpm помогло уже часа 4 мучался с этим. Ответите обширней чтоб я выбрал как правильный ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При изменении кофигурации php требуется либо рестарт

```
~# systemctl restart php7.0-fpm
```

что равносильно stop-start.
Либо, что идеологически правильнее (IMHO), если речь идет о "боевом" сервере, - перезагрузка параметров

```
~# systemctl reload php7.0-fpm
```

некоторые службы не умеют reload, в этом случае можно сделать

```
~# systemctl force-reload [service_name]
```

тогда после безуспешной попытки reload будет автоматически сделан restart